# How do I read $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{r\times 1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1},y\to X_y$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N},1\leqslant r\leqslant n$,$X_1,...,X_r\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ and consider $X=[X_1...X_r]\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$
>
> The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i)$X_1,...,X_r$ are linearly independent.
>
> (ii)$car(X)=r$(characteristic of the matrix, rank)
>
> (iii)$\det(X^tX)=0$

**Proof** By definition $car(X)=\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(Im(\phi))$, where

$\phi:\mathbb{R}^{r\times 1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1},y\to X_y$

The linear map $\phi$ is determined by the images of a basis $e_1,...,e_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^{r\times 1}$, and $Im(\phi)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ generated by $\phi(e_1),...,\phi(e_n)$. Therefore $car(X)=r$ iff $X_1,...,X_r$ are linearly independent.

**Questions:**

I am not understanding the map$\phi:\mathbb{R}^{r\times 1}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1},y\to X_y$. Is it mapping each member of $X_r$ to $X_n$? Is $y\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times 1}$, the index of $X_i$?

How can $e_1,...,e_n$ has $n$ elements if it belongs to $\mathbb{R^{r\times 1}}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure $X$ is not a $(n+1)\times(r+1)$ matrix instead of $n\times r$?

Comment: @AOrtiz                    In the material I am studying it is $n\times r$.I cannot see the transformation. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Very strange. Unless I’m misreading the notation, $X$ is being thought of as a matrix whose columns are the $X_r$, but those are vectors with $n+1$ components, so something is amiss here.

Comment: @AOrtiz                   Do you know where can I find a similar theorem, so that I can look at another proof?

Comment: @AOrtiz - what is amiss is that you are reading $n \times 1$ as $n + 1$.

Comment: The definition of $\phi$ should be $\phi(y) = Xy$, that is, the product of $X$ and the vector $y$. In other words, $\phi$ is just $X$ considered as a linear transformation and not a matrix. As you've noticed, $X_y$ makes no sense as the subscripts of $X_i$ are integers, while $y$ is a vector.